# why property of prototype is not showing as portoype property in an javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I have following code  :

```
function A(){
  this.a='a'
}
A.prototype.b='b';
Function.prototype.m='m';
```

now i am creating an object of Type `A` and console

```
var obj=new A();
console.log(obj)//it return {a: "a", b: "b"}
```

1. here constructor function `A` has only one property `a`, and prototype of A has one property `b`. so why `obj` return `{a: "a", b: "b"}`. the `b` property is in the prototype so it should be in __porto_ property.
2. why `Function` prototype property is not showing in `__porto__` property in `obj` object.it should be `__porto__` because it is parent prototype of `obj` object.

Comment: It depends on what browser you use to log and how many properties you have. If I remember correctly Chrome will show an object like this if all enumerable members fit but add another 20 or so members and you get the expandable output. In that output you'll see b under proto

Answer (score 1):

A regarding you second part of your question, it is because the line

```
var a = new A();
```

can be written as well like this:

```
var a = Object.create(A.prototype);
A.call(a);
```

you can see that no object is created from `Function.prototype`.

Regarding the first part - in which environment you get that behaviour? the obj should contain `{a: "a"}`